# jQuery replace - styling numbers

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

i want to style specific characters inside my <code> tag. 
so i google and found the .replace() function. but i had problems on styling numbers. i want to change it's style without changing it's text.

here is my code:

HTML

```
<code> $years = floor($diff / (365*60*60*24)); </code>
```

JS

```
('code').each(function()
{
    var text = $(this).text(); 
    var setan = text.replace(/\d+/g,'<int>'+'\d'+'</int>');
    $(this).html(setan); 
});
```

the output is `$years = floor($diff / (d*d*d*d));`

i want to make it at least like `$years = floor($diff / (<b>d</b>*<b>d</b>*<b>d</b>*<b>d<b>));`

Comment: You probably want a capture group, unless you want the character "d" instead of those numbers - Ex: `.replace(/(\d+)/g,'<b>$1</b>')`

Comment: Is expected result to return numbers as bold text , or character "d" as bold text ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I have understood, you want numbers to be presented there, but not `d` letters.

You can use capture groups for replacing.
That's how you can do this:

```js
$("code").each(function() {
    var text = $(this).text();
    $(this).html(text.replace(/(\d+)/g, '<int>$1</int>')); // here you can place any tags
});
```

```css
int { 
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<code>$years = floor($diff / (365*60*60*24));</code>
```

Answer (score 4):

Better to use css class to style the element like

```js
$('code').html(function() {
  var text = $(this).text();
  return text.replace(/\d+/g, '<span class="d">' + 'd' + '</span>');
});
```

```css
code span.d {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<code> $years = floor($diff / (365*60*60*24)); </code>
```

Comment: Then add a style rule to the class

Answer (score 2):

> i want to make it at least like `$years = floor($diff /
>   (<b>d</b>*<b>d</b>*<b>d</b>*<b>d</b>));`

Try substituting `<b></b>` for `<int></int>` at replacement text , utilizing `.html(function(index, html){})`

```js
$("code").html(function(_, html) {
    return html.replace(/\d+/g,"<b>d</b>");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<code> $years = floor($diff / (365*60*60*24)); </code>
```

Comment: @NandaPandyatama So, do you want to look like `d*d*d*d` or like `365*60*60*24` and colored? You haven't answered this question.

Comment: 365*60*60*24 and colored.. i've solved this.. i have error on my jQuery.. so it wont change..